# Does capillary blood pressure have any effect on how much oxygen or nutrient gets distributed to tissues?

Tags: hematology, blood-circulation, blood-pressure, circulatory-system

From what I have read regarding blood pressure and blood flow, I've come to the conclusion that, apart from the osmolarity of blood, the only determinant of how much oxygen/nutrients the tissues get per unit time, is blood flow.

Does blood pressure (not systemic, but within a theoretical capillary) have absolutely no effect on this, and if so, why? Intuitively, it seems to me that if the force by blood on the walls of a capillary increases, that would imply a higher number of molecules touching endothelial cells, and thus a higher likelihood of molecule transport per unit time.

Or is it perhaps that they both have positive effects on oxygenation/nutrient transport; but blood flow's effect greatly excels that of blood pressure?